# In C++., how to use maximum-difference threshold to find cluster average values

Tags: c++, statistics

I need help setting up a C++ module to iterate through the 2D plot below in order to accumulate the mean of each cluster by detecting a maximum threshold difference, seen at each step. For example, when the threshold is reaching of let's say 25 between the points, all points from the current cluster should be averaged out and assigned a parameter to print out.

I hope this makes sense, please ask questions for clarification if needed.

[image: Text]

I'm looking for a simple method to achieve this in C++.

Comment: I'm afraid SO is not a code writing service. You should try doing it yourself and if you get stuck at something particular, ask it here and that would be a [good SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is the plot itself in a collection (array, vector etc?) or are you asking if there's a way to send the 2D image itself as a parameter and parse it in the function?

Comment: plot could be an array or vector. Not interested in passing the image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code that does what you requested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::vector<float> samples = {1.f,2.f,3.f,30.f,31.f,32.f};
    std::vector<float> clustersAvg; // the averages per cluster
    float clusterAcc =0.f; // current cluster accumulated values
    int clusterSize = 0; // current cluster size
    float lastSample = samples[0];
    for (const auto&sample:samples)
    {
        if (abs(sample - lastSample) <= 25) // check if threshold is reached or not
        {
            clusterAcc += sample;
            clusterSize ++;

        }
        else
        {
            // threshold reached, let's average what we accumulated so far
            clustersAvg.push_back(clusterAcc/clusterSize);
            clusterAcc = sample;
            clusterSize = 1;
        }
        lastSample = sample; // keep track of sample for next threshold checking
    }

    clustersAvg.push_back(clusterAcc/clusterSize); // last accumulation

    // print results
    for (const auto & avg:clustersAvg)
    {
        cout << "avg: " << avg << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: hello @Farnsworth did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

There are millions of possible solutions.

Here the next one.

The algorithm of all solutions will be similar. Check, if there is a "jump" in sample data that is greater than the threshold. This we find out by iterating over data and then comparing the current element with the next element. We subtract the values, and check, if the sbsolute value is bigger then the treshold. Then we show the result.

If not, then we are building a running sum and count the samples for the later avaerage calculation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // Test Data. Here in a vector, can be any other container
    std::vector sample{
        1,2,1,3,2,1,3,4,2,3,5,2,3,
        30,29,32,28,33,32,34,31,35,34,31,
        82,81,83,86,84,86,87,85,86,82,
        111,112,113,112,114,115,113,112,113 };

    // Some threshold example
    constexpr int threshold{ 20 };

    // Here we count the elements in one group of somehow similare sample values
    int groupCounter{};
    // And this is the sum of one group of somehow similar sample values
    double groupSum{};

    // Check all sample data
    for (size_t i{}; i < sample.size(); ++i) {

        // Accumulate the data
        groupSum += sample[i];
        ++groupCounter;

        // If we have a "jump" or are at the last value
        if ((i == sample.size() - 1) || (std::abs(sample[i + 1] - sample[i]) > threshold)) {

            // Prevent division by 0
            if (groupCounter > 0) {
                // Show resulting avaerage of this group
                std::cout << "Average value:\t" << groupSum / groupCounter << '\n';
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "\nError: No further data\n";
            }
            // Reset values to do calculations for the next run
            groupCounter = 0;
            groupSum = 0.0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using C++ algorithms you will get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

// Abbreviations for easier writing
using Container = std::vector<double>;
using Iter = Container::iterator;

int main() {

    // The test data
    Container sample{ 1,2,1,3,2,1,3, 30,29,32,28,33,32, 82,81,83,86,84,86, 112,114,115,113,112,113};

    // Some threshold
    constexpr double threshold = 20.0;

    // Simple For loop. Go over container from start to end
    for (Iter result{}, start = {sample.begin()}; start != sample.end(); start = result)
    {
            // Search the "jump" in data
            result = std::adjacent_find(start, sample.end(),
                [threshold](const double& d1, const double& d2) { return std::abs(d1 - d2) > threshold; });

            // Set result to the next element after the found value
            result = (result != sample.end()) ? std::next(result) : sample.end();

            // Show result of calculation to user
            std::cout << std::accumulate(start, result, 0.0) / std::distance(start, result) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```